# Clicking on desktop makes GTK3 window disappear

Tags: c, gtk, gtk3

The following code produces a GTK3 window that avoids the taskbar and the pager and sets type hint GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DESKTOP.

When the code is executed, a click on my desktop makes the window disappear. Removing the type hint solves the problem but then a "Show desktop" operation also makes the window disappear forever.

Is this the expected behavior of GTK3? If yes, how can I obtain a persistent window that avoids the taskbar and the pager and does not disappear on "show desktop" or clicking on the desktop?

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void activate(GtkApplication *app) {
  GtkWidget *window=gtk_application_window_new(app);
  gtk_window_set_skip_taskbar_hint(GTK_WINDOW(window),1);
  gtk_window_set_skip_pager_hint(GTK_WINDOW(window),1);
  gtk_window_set_type_hint(GTK_WINDOW(window),GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DESKTOP);
  gtk_widget_show_all(window);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  GtkApplication *app=gtk_application_new(NULL,G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect(app,"activate",G_CALLBACK(activate),NULL);
  int status=g_application_run(G_APPLICATION(app),argc,argv);
  g_object_unref(app);
  return status;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DOCK to have the desired behavior.

That is:

- "Show desktop" does not make the window disappear.
- Clicking on desktop does not make the window disappear.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Windows.html#GdkWindowTypeHint

GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DESKTOP - Used for creating the desktop background window. (do not use this, unless you are making the desktop background application)

GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN - Does this work for you?

GDK_WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_DIALOG - Or maybe this?